# Is the fully constructed State Trie persisted to disk?

Tags: storage

On Substrate, is the fully constructed State Trie persisted to disk or only the State Trie root hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire state trie is persisted to disk currently. Not just only the root hash.